# How to prevent an element from scrolling *only* via mousemove without preventing selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a situation where I have text input elements near the edge of the page, and when using the mouse to select all the text inside one of those inputs, the page scrolls to the left. I don't want this to happen.

I *do* need the page to be scrollable left to right normally, and I don't want to disable selection. I also don't want to disable scrolling while items are being dragged via the drag-and-drop API.

I can do:

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

But that disables both selection and dragging via the drag-and-drop API. I suppose I could lock the scrollbar in place on mousedown and unlock on mouseup, and then unlock on dragstart, and detect mouseover in the right areas to perform scroll when I *do* want it, but there's gonna be a ton of error prone edge cases in doing that.

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates the issue. Try selecting the "hi" text with your mouse: https://jsfiddle.net/f7e9z9os/

Is there any clean way to do this via javascript or css?

Comment: maybe disable the scrolling as you do and enable when drag and drop event starts and disable when drag and drop ends?

Comment: @RohitHazra That would work if I didn't want the user to be able to use the scrollbar, which I do want.

Comment: so you want that when the user clicks on that select box, your page does not scroll? but they can use scroll bar when they need. first I really cant see a design where such a thing cannot be prevented but seeing your SO i think you are doing something such that you cannot prevent this design pattern.... so how about when the user selects you us js to scroll the page to rightmost. ?

Comment: maybe share a screen shot to make the view clear?

Comment: @RohitHazra I added a js fiddle that demonstrates the issue

Comment: why this `document.body.scrollLeft = document.body.scrollWidth` if I remove this then the body doesnt automatically scroll, as for selecting, the scrolling stops as soon as I stop scrolling (clicking + dragging). You are aware that clicking on something and dragging your mouse actually triggers your scroll bars and they are the same actions ?

Comment: maybe you can implement onClick Select all ? that wont need the user to select the text but that is if they have to select everything always.

Comment: @RohitHazra I am aware of those things. The `document.body.scrollLeft = ...` code ensures its in the state that demonstrates the issue - which corresponds to the state in my actual application where there is space to scroll on the left. I could do an on-click select all, but that would be a detriment to the usability of the application.

Comment: mouseDown + scroll is equivalent/shortcut to using scroll bar. so what you are trying seems to deem impossible. to be honest if a user is doing the aforementioned action they need to see what they are selecting and hence the denying that will be breaking the system?

Comment: "mouseDown + scroll is equivalent/shortcut to using scroll bar" - they are not the same and differentiating them is possible, but annoyingly difficult. The user will be able to see the things they need to select in my app without drag scrolling

Comment: maybe you can check the pointer location ? if it is at bottom or right most then allow scrolling ? also how would you differentiate between mousedown + drag (on window) and mousedown + drag (on scrollbar) except for maybe what i gave above but that can be complicated.

if you use something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll then I dont think it can differentiate between the two.

Comment: @RohitHazra That's an interesting idea. Not perfect, but it solves maybe 95% of the problem. I might do that, thanks!